# Magento - Load local.xml based on environment

Tags: magento

I want to have 3 `app/etc/local.xml` files - call them local.xml staging.xml and live.xml.

I want to load these based on an environment variable that I set in either the vhosts or the htaccess.  This way I can have seperate databases etc but 1 codebase that I can keep under svn.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

`local.xml` is *hardcoded* in multiple Magento files.

So if you want to implement your own file name selection for this, you'd have to *override* several core classes/methods/functions respectively.

A scan for `local.xml`* shows that - amongst other things - you'd have to modify `/app/Mage.php`. That's because you cannot override `Mage` (it's a `final` class).

Be aware that modifying `/app/Mage.php` is possible, but every upgrade to the next Magento version will overwrite your changes.

If you can live with that, you'd additionally have to override at least

```
Mage_Core_Model_Config
Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update
```

and maybe additionally

```
Mage_Install_Model_Installer_Config
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Notification_Security (1.5.1)
```

depending on your needs.

### Implementation

Setup your file name selection method, e.g. in a helper:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data
{
    public function getLocalXMLFileName()
    {
        return getenv('MY_XML') . 'xml';
    }    
}
```

In your overridden core classes just call your helper method, e.g. change

```
$updateFiles[] = 'local.xml';
```

to

```
$updateFiles[] = Mage::helper('mymodule')->getLocalXMLFileName();
```

---

<sub>* I only scanned 1.3.2.x, 1.5.1 and 1.8.1.0. In other versions more/less classes maybe affected.</sub>

1.3.2.x:

```
./app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Config.php:49:
    $this->_localConfigFile = Mage::getBaseDir('etc').DS.'local.xml';

./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php:283:
    $updateFiles[] = 'local.xml';

./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:214:
    $localConfigLoaded  = $this->loadFile($etcDir.DS.'local.xml');

./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:248:
    $configFile  = $etcDir.DS.'local.xml';

./app/Mage.php:521:
    $localConfigFile = self::getRoot() . DS . $etcDir . DS . 'local.xml';
```

1.5.1:

```
./app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Config.php:49:
    $this->_localConfigFile = Mage::getBaseDir('etc').DS.'local.xml';

./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php:418:
    $updateFiles[] = 'local.xml';

./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:280:
    if (in_array($etcDir.DS.'local.xml', $files)) {

./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:322:
    $this->_isLocalConfigLoaded = $mergeConfig->
        loadFile($this->getOptions()->getEtcDir().DS.'local.xml');

./app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Security.php:36:
    private $_filePath = 'app/etc/local.xml';

./app/Mage.php:671:
    $localConfigFile = self::getRoot() . DS . $etcDir . DS . 'local.xml';

./errors/processor.php:34:
    const MAGE_ERRORS_LOCAL_XML = 'local.xml';
```

1.8.1.0:

```
./app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Config.php:49:
    $this->_localConfigFile = Mage::getBaseDir('etc') . DS . 'local.xml';

./app/code/core/Mage/Install/Model/Installer/Config.php:103:
    $template = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('etc') . DS . 'local.xml.template');

./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:280:
    if (in_array($etcDir.DS.'local.xml', $files)) {

./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:324:
    $this->_isLocalConfigLoaded =
        $mergeConfig->loadFile($this->getOptions()->getEtcDir().DS.'local.xml');

./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php:311:
    // $updateFiles[] = 'local.xml';

./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php:431:
    $updateFiles[] = 'local.xml';

./app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Security.php:36:
    private $_filePath = 'app/etc/local.xml';

./app/Mage.php:762:
    $localConfigFile = $etcDir . DS . 'local.xml';

./errors/processor.php:34:
   const MAGE_ERRORS_LOCAL_XML = 'local.xml';
```

Comment: Would this method work with later versions of Magento such as 1.8.x (which is the latest version at this time 03/2014)

Comment: @Zabs: didn't tested it, but looking at the 1.8.1.0 matches, I'd say: yes, it should.

Comment: +1 for returning to such an old question and giving an update! :)