# magento resource connection per server

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way to have magento pick what DB it connects to depending on what server it's being run from?

So I don't have to keep changing everything.

IE: Development, Staging, Production?

Comment: Do you have some way to just exclude local.xml in your deployment process?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Magento - Load local.xml based on environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191894/magento-load-local-xml-based-on-environment/6199616#6199616).

Comment: This kinda is a dup, but I definitely don't see the need for 3 separate files, you should be able to populate everything in one file w/ XML and then do a simple server/environment name look-up to determine which config you want to load - which will then use the proper database configs

Comment: I see. Maybe you can find a single method used by _all_ of the hardcoded `local.xml` occurences. I never analyzed that. If they _all_ are based on `Mage_Core_Model_Config_Base`, it could come down to just a conditional assignment of the proper value to the `::_xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host` node.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without touching core files. In the `index.php` you see last line: `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`. There is 3rd parameter here, so you can try something like:

```
$params = array (
    'options' => array(
        'etc_dir' => 'your_dir'
    )
);
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType, $params);
```

But in this case you need separate etc folder for each server. Probably it isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: This is good insight - I didn't know about this feature, but not 100% what i was looking for.  I might have to try and write an extension or something that won't break upgrades and handles what I'm looking for. I wonder if anyone else is looking for this functionality?  How do people handle this situation when they're running a CI server? or multiple environments on their way to production?

Comment: We use teamcity on our CI server. We have `local.xml.ci` file and we copy it to `local.xml` in ant build script. I think this is better than have settings for 3 servers in the same `local.xml` as you wish.